# Генерация случайных десятичных чисел

Tags: php

У меня есть два числа 1.5 и 2.5
Вопрос: Как генерировать случайные числа в этом диапазоне? rand/mt_rand округляют до целых значений, т.е. выводят либо 1, либо 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [lcg_value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php). В примерах к функции есть варианты генерации  вещественного числа в пределах заданного диапазона.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rand = rand(15,25)/10;
```

так ?

Answer (score 0):

Ну если диапозон настолько мал, можно записать массив этого диапазона от 1.5 до 2.5 и mt_rand работать по ключу массива.